# facebook prevent auth dialog

Tags: facebook, authentication

In my FB canvas app, I don't request any permissions, nor do I request permissions using the scope parameter, yet the auth dialog still shows up. How can I make it not show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not requesting any *extended* permissions in the scope parameter.  You are, in fact, asking for permission to see the user's user ID, name, avatar image, and other basic information that the user might or might not want to publicize

Comment: Is there any way to get around the auth dialog showing up, using any of the FB APIs, or is it just something we have to live with?

Comment: yes, facebook will not let you access any of a user's information without that user agreeing to it first